# SQS JMS Implementation Listener hang issue

Tags: java, jms, amazon-sqs, jms-topic, sqslistener

I have a requirement in which I want to consume multiple `SQS` topic from a single `java process`. Below is the sample code:

```
public class MultiTopicSQSConsumer {
    Connection connection;
    private void init(){
        try {
            AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("accessKey", "secretKey"));
            SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
                    .region(Region.of("regionName"))
                    .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
            SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(
                    new ProviderConfiguration(),
                    sqsClient
            );
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create connection. Error - " + ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void createConsumer(String queueName){
        try {
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) {
                    // handle message  
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create session. Error - " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine. But in case of high load like 10 `consumers`(each for different queue) for the message listener hangs and recovers after long time (hours after receiving the message).
Is it a expected behavior or there is something wrong with the implementation.